# Java Customized GroupingBy with || Condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to see if I'm able group by multiple keys.
let's say I got a class:

```
Class Something {
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

And a list of things:

```
  Name     id

  David    123
  David    456
  Bryant   123
  Ryan     456
  Foo      555
  Bar      555
```

And I can group them into

```
[(David, 123), (David, 456), (Bryant, 123), (Ryan, 456)]
[(Foo, 555), (Bar, 555)]
```

Which mean, the behavior that I want for the class "equals" to be is either name or id is the same, the class equals, such that

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Something that = (Something) o;
    return this.name.equals(that.name) || this.id.equals(that.id);
}
```

But the problem with that equals function is non-transitive, which means I can't write a corresponding hashCode function for it.

I know that if I write two hashmaps, I can achieve this by doing

```
Map<String, Something> idToSomething;
Map<String, Something> nameToSomething;
```

Now the question is, how should I achieve the behavior I want by using Collections, say if those things are in a List called somethings, so I can do something similar to

```
somethings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupby(???))
```

Note that I also want to be able to change ??? easily in future by applying different grouping by strategy, say I might want to just group by name or id in future.

Comment: You might want to look at Google Guava's Multimap

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this would be to make a method that determines the `Function<? super Something, ? extends String>` to use as the classifier to pass to `Collectors#groupingBy` and use a global variable to determine which should be used:

```
private boolean shouldIdBeUsed = true;

public Function<? super Something, ? extends String> getClassifier() {
    if (shouldIdBeUsed) {
        return Something::getId;
    }

    return Something::getName;
}
```

Now, you can simply pass the method as a parameter:

```
somethings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(getClassifier()));
```

Comment: hmm... but it would always be either id to be used or name to be used. That boolean needs to be true and false at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I provided an example.  You can remove the boolean and add any other conditions you want.

Answer (score 0):

A bit extended answer of Jacob.

```
        Map<UUID, List<BookingOutput.CostsQuoteSummary>> quotesPerUsers = bookings.stream()
            .map(booking -> new BookingOutput.CostsQuoteSummary(
                    booking,
                    timesheet.getDates().getFrom(),
                    timesheet.getDates().getTo()
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(groupCostsPerUser(uuidGenerator)));
```

There we add `groupCostsPerUser(uuidGenerator)` method with encapsulating any conditions we need. Sample in my case:

```
private Function<BookingOutput.CostsQuoteSummary, UUID> groupCostsPerUser(UUIDGenerator uuidGenerator) {
    return costsQuoteSummary -> costsQuoteSummary.hasUserId() ? costsQuoteSummary.getUserId()
            : uuidGenerator.generateV4(); 
}
```